# there is no option of Team Explorer menu in my visual code studio how can I get that option

Tags: visual-studio

actually happened that I select all my file in source control by mistake and then I am not able to deselect
it was showing your file are pending to edit, or something like that. Then I come back to desktop page.
and again I open VS code and my all files are disappear. and also disappear from my machine also. Now I want my all files back. what can I do next??

I tried to find my file but I not able to found. and I also try to find team explorer but also it is
not showing and I am expecting that your team will help me and I will get my files back..